# Creating Workflow from asp.net form

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio, sharepoint-server, asp.net

I have deployed an **asp.net web form** in an application page in SharePoint 2013. The form was developed in Visual Studio 2013 with asp.net being used to build the form and vb.net for the code behind. I am wanting to build a workflow on this form I have deployed, in Visual Studio 2013. Can anyone provide me with any guidance on how this can be done? I know I will need to some how link the form in the application page to the workflow, but I am not sure as to how to do that.. Maybe Visual Studio isn't the best route to do the workflow in, I am open to anyone's opinions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a SharePoint workflow and have it started via code in the application page.  The REST API has methods for starting workflows.

If you application page is packaged as a solution ( it should be) you can add a workflow to the solution as well.  Just use a site scoped workflow or if you an accompany list use a list scoped workflow.

Comment: I did add a state machine WF to my solution file, but when I click the submit button on the form in the application page, it doesn't begin the WF.. Any idea why that would happen? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry you're not providing enough info.  Did you wire up the button to start the workflow? Are you using SharePoint workflow?  If you use .net native WF it doesn't just work with SharePoint.

Comment: I added the state machine WF in VS by right clicking my solution and Add -> Add New Item -> then under "Office/SharePoint I added the "State Machine WF (Farm Solution Only). So the WF is now part of the solution along with my form and code behind. I have not wired up the submit button to "Start" the WF and I believe the WF is a SP WF... Based on the steps I provided above, doesn't it sound like it is? This is the first WF I have done with SP, so am very new at this in explaining what I have. Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: I have also looked up the command to "Start" the WF, but have been unable to find any good information.

Comment: MSDN has posted examples of working with the workflow service. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn481315(v=office.15).aspx#sectionSection2